# Video error with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, video

I am trying to put a video into my website using html5.
The sound of the video plays, however you can just see a black space.
I have used the basic `<video>`from w3schools. My code looks like this...

```
<video width="420" height="315" controls>
<source src="myMovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="myMovie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: In which browser and system is this?

Comment: You could use http://html5test.com/ to check if your browser and system supports html5

Comment: I have tested the video on my laptop at home as well as several computers at my university and still it doesn't work. All the computers I have tested use Windows 7 and the browsers are Chrome, IE and firefox

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it can be your graphic card, have you googled black screen on html5 video? You might wanna add you graphic card and ios to your search.

Unless you use browser that doesnt support html5. If that's the case, get a html5 browser and try it out :)

Comment: I have tested my video on my home laptop and several computers in my university. I have also tested the video in Chrome, IE and Firefox and it still only shows a black screen